# Fire event on repeat done in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Hello I am trying to fire a event on repeat done in AngularJS, following is the code:

Following is the HTML code

```
<li ng-repeat="y in names | limitTo: 6" repeat-done="ratingwithng()"> <a href="<?php echo $this->config->item('search_url');?>{{y.hosurl}}">
  <div class="hospital-card"> <img src="{{y.profile_image}}" width="" height="" />
    <h3 class="vlcc-name">{{y.clinic_name}}</h3>
    <div class="doc-rete">
      <div id="rateYo-hos" class="mc-doc-rating">3</div>
    </div>
    <p class="hospital-specialist">{{y.localty }} {{y.city }}</p>
    <p class="vlcc-experince">{{y.clinic_type }}</p>
    <p class="vlcc-address">{{y.hos_time }} </p>
  </div>
  </a>
</li>
```

Following is the AngularJS code:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {   
   $http.get("frontendapi/hospital_list")
   .then(function (response) {$scope.names = response.data.HospitalList;});  

    $http.get("frontendapi/NewsList")
   .then(function (response) {$scope.namesNews = response.data.Newslistfeature;});

   $http.get("frontendapi/NewsList")
   .then(function (response) {$scope.namesNewsRec = response.data.Newslist;});

   $http.get("frontendapi/NewsList")
   .then(function (response) {$scope.nameDoctor = response.data.records;});

   $http.get("frontendapi/people_list")
   .then(function (response) {$scope.nameDoctorShift = response.data.PeopleList;});

   $http.get("frontendapi/interviews_list")
   .then(function (response) {$scope.nameInterview = response.data.interviewslist;});

});
function ratingwithng()
{
    alert();
}
```

Alert is not working, please suggest.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function must be one the `$scope` object for that controller to be visible on the `ng-repeat`

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {   
   $http.get("frontendapi/hospital_list")
   .then(function (response) {$scope.names = response.data.HospitalList;});  

    $http.get("frontendapi/NewsList")
   .then(function (response) {$scope.namesNews = response.data.Newslistfeature;});

   $http.get("frontendapi/NewsList")
   .then(function (response) {$scope.namesNewsRec = response.data.Newslist;});

   $http.get("frontendapi/NewsList")
   .then(function (response) {$scope.nameDoctor = response.data.records;});

   $http.get("frontendapi/people_list")
   .then(function (response) {$scope.nameDoctorShift = response.data.PeopleList;});

   $http.get("frontendapi/interviews_list")
   .then(function (response) {$scope.nameInterview = response.data.interviewslist;});

   $scope.ratingwithng = function ()
   {
      alert();
   }

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately the alert is not working, even there is nothing in console

Answer (score 1):

You shoud have the function as,

```
$scope.ratingwithng =function()
{
    alert('test');
}
```

Comment: @SanjeevK are you sure?